# how to customise UITableView?

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, uitableview

How to add image and texts as shown in the below snapshots?I am already using navigation controller in my application, so is there any problem in including UITableView controller as a new navigated page from home page.[image: like this page I am trying to make my application![][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would subclass the UITableView Cell and create my own cell `MyCustomTableViewCell`, with the UIImageView and UILabel inside.

Then you could do this to update your cells in reusing case

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

    MyCustomTableViewCell *myCell = (MyCustomTableViewCell)cell;
    myCell.label.text = newText;
    myCell.imageView.image = newImage;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code.. but i have created a UITableView controller. Then now what i have to do before doing this code? And how could i add UITableView cell?

Comment: Just read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html :)

Answer (score 2):

when configuring your `UITableViewCell`you can add a `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to the cells `contentView`.

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;

    UIImageView *yourImageView = ...;

    UILabel *yourLabel = ...;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:yourImageView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:yourLabel];
```

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: Sure, this is the place to go.